# set responsive to 768px width

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Bootstrap not putting two menu items into hamburger.
Lower than 768px works fine but upper than 768 not in hamburger menu.

Im using bootstrap 4.5.2

My code:

```
<header id="header" class="fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light container-fluid">
        <div class="mr-auto d-flex">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <img height="65px" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" alt="SweetHelp">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto d-flex align-items-center">
            <ul id="header-contact" class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item d-md-block d-none">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-btn-regular mr-3" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url() ?>"><?php _e('Cart', 'rv'); ?> <span class="header-cart-count"> <?php echo '(' . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . ')'; ?></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-md-block d-none">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-btn mr-4" href="<?php echo wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );?>"><?php _e('Shop', 'rv'); ?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav-opener" onclick="openNav()">
                <i class="fal fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div id="menu-area">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light container-fluid">
                <div class="ml-auto d-flex">
                    <div class="menu-close d-flex align-items-center" onclick="closeNav()">
                        <span class="mr-3"><?php _e('Close', 'rv'); ?></span><i class="fal fa-times fa-2x"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <ul class="navbar-nav pt-md-4 pl-md-4 pb-md-4 pt-0 pl-4 pt-4 pr-4">
                <li class="nav-item d-md-none d-block">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-btn mb-2" href="<?php echo wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );?>"><?php _e('Shop', 'rv'); ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                    'depth'           => 1,
                    'container'       => false,
                    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                ) ); ?>
                <li class="nav-item d-md-none d-block">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-btn-regular" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url() ?>"><?php _e('Ostukorv', 'rv'); ?><span class="header-cart-count"> <?php echo '(' . WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . ')'; ?></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I want shop and cart will be in burger menu so long when it shows burger menu.

Comment: So edit your styles to always be in burger shape. Bootstrap controls it to be in burger only on small screen

Comment: changed navbar-expand-lg to navbar-expand-md worked!